# ArrayAdapter text filtering breaks in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, drawerlayout

I have the unfortunate feeling that this is simply a bug with Android, being that DrawerLayout is still relatively new.

Basically what I have is a ListView, with an ArrayAdapter set on it. I was previously performing textfilter searching without any problems. But then I decided to implement a DrawerLayout into the layout. As soon as the drawer is added, the text filtering breaks.

Where before, the software keyboard would pop up, you would begin typing (your typing overlaid on the screen), and the list would filter by that string.

With the drawer layout, the keyboard pops up, but nothing happens when things are typed.

I am positive that the drawer layout is somehow responsible for this, because as soon as I removed the layout code, the search functionality began working again.

For reference, here's my XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/header_container">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/header_text" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/header_text"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/header_text"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/searchbutton"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_search"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/header_text"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/searchbutton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/headerClassField"/>
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header_text"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:id="@+id/spell_list_view" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/drawer_spell_list"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the drawer code which is being included:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="240dp"
              android:layout_gravity="left"
              android:background="@color/midnight_blue"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/star"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_metamagic_link"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/drawer_metamagic"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/drawer_border"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/inward_arrows"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_longclick_link"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/drawer_longclick"/>
    </LinearLayout>



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:text="..."/>

    <include layout="@layout/drawer_main"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The drawer works perfectly, but the search doesn't when the drawer is included. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Interestingly enough, the filter doesn't break if I use a SlidingPanelLayout as opposed to a DrawerLayout. That may need to be my workaround.

Comment: I too an having issues with DrawerLayout. I switch my inner views out for fragments and now the hidden view does not swipe out anymore.

Comment: My problem was not setting layout gravity. Unrelated to your issue.